# Calculating the spectral correlation tensor in quantum optics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-optics, correlation-functions, cavity-qed

Given an electromagnetic field bath, by the Hamiltonian
$$
H_B = \sum\limits_{\mathbf{k}}\sum\limits_{\lambda\in\{1,2\}}
        \hbar \omega_{\mathbf{k}} b^\dagger_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k})b^{\phantom{\dagger}}_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k})
$$
and a dipole interaction, given by $H_{SB} = - \mathbf{D}\cdot \mathbf{E}$, where
$$
\mathbf{E} = i \sum\limits_{\mathbf{k}}\sum\limits_{\lambda\in\{1,2\}}
        \sqrt{\frac{2\pi \hbar\omega_\mathbf{k}}{V}} \mathbf{e}_\lambda(\mathbf{k}) \left(b^{\phantom{\dagger}}_\lambda(\mathbf{k}) - b^{\dagger}_\lambda(\mathbf{k})\right).
$$
is the electric field operator in Schrödinger-picture. I have to calculate the bath correlation tensor,
$$
 \Gamma_{ij}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\hbar^2} \int\limits_0^\infty \textrm{d} s e^{i\omega s} \langle E_i(t) E_j(t-s) \rangle,
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{E}(t) = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}H_Bt}\mathbf{E}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}H_Bt}
$$
is the electric field operator in interaction-picture.
I wanted to do the calculation for two cases:

- For vacuum bath: $\rho_B = | 0 \rangle\langle 0 |$
- For a thermal    bath: $\rho_B = \prod\limits_{\mathbf{k},   
     \lambda}(1-\exp[-\beta\hbar\omega_{\mathbf k}])\exp[-\beta\hbar   
     \omega_{\mathbf{k}}   
     b^\dagger_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k})b^{\phantom{\dagger}}_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k})]$

**My attempt 1:**
We can use the fact that the state of the bath is stationary, i.e.,
$$
\langle E_i(t) E_j(t-s) \rangle = \langle E_i(s) E_j(0) \rangle = 
\left\langle e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}H_Bs}E_ie^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}H_Bs} E_j \right\rangle .
$$
Then we calculate $\mathbf{E}(s)$ using the formula:
$$
\begin{align}
         \mathbf{E}(s) &= e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}H_Bs}\mathbf{E}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}H_Bs} \\
         &=\sum\limits_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}'}\sum\limits_{\lambda,\lambda'\in\{1,2\}}
         e^{i\omega_{\mathbf{k}}s} b^\dagger_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k})b^{\phantom{\dagger}}_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k}) \mathbf{E}
         e^{-i\omega_{\mathbf{k'}}s} b^\dagger_{\lambda'}(\mathbf{k}')b^{\phantom{\dagger}}_{\lambda'}(\mathbf{k'}) \\
         &=\sum\limits_{
         \substack{{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'},\mathbf{k''}} \\ {\lambda,\lambda',{\lambda''}\in\{1,2\}}
         }}
         e^{i\omega_{\mathbf{k}}s} b^\dagger_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k})b^{\phantom{\dagger}}_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k}) 
         \left[
             i
            \sqrt{\frac{2\pi \hbar\omega_\mathbf{k''}}{V}} \mathbf{e}_{\lambda''}(\mathbf{k''}) \left(b^{\phantom{\dagger}}_{\lambda''}(\mathbf{k''}) - b^{\dagger}_{\lambda''}(\mathbf{k''})\right) 
        \right] e^{-i\omega_{\mathbf{k'}}s} b^\dagger_{\lambda'}(\mathbf{k}')b^{\phantom{\dagger}}_{\lambda'}(\mathbf{k'})
    \end{align}
$$
This quickly gets very complicated, and I don't know if it's worth continuing from here.
 **My attempt 2:** 
Use that
$$
\langle E_i(s) E_j(0) \rangle = \textrm{Tr}_B\left[E_i(s) E_j(0) \rho_B\right]
$$
Inserting the expressions of $\mathbf{E}(s)$ and $\rho_B$ to this formula seems also very complicated.
Is there a more clever, or easier way of calculating $\Gamma_{ij}(\omega)$?

Comment: Can you simplify the formula in the 1st attempt, by evolving each component of E separately? How do the creation and annihilation operators with different λ act on each other?